# How do I print without truncation in ipython qtconsole?

Tags: python, ipython

If I print a large object in ipython, it will be truncated.  For example:

```
print gb.describe()

size   val                      
large  val0                                  count    465.000000
                                             mean      -3.929402
                                             std       18.947443
                                             min     -173.843226
                                             25%       -1.029557
                                             50%       -1.000000
                                             75%       -0.995420
                                             max       20.743233
       val1                                  count    403.000000
                                             mean      -0.966699
                                             std        0.763963
                                             min       -7.583054
                                             25%       -1.000016
                                             50%       -1.000000
                                             75%       -0.999966
...
small  val6                   mean        320.291906
                              std        7802.337528
                              min      -18102.497172
                              25%          -1.000177
                              50%          -1.000000
                              75%          -0.999875
                              max      163817.549404
       val7                   count        96.000000
                              mean         -0.161794
                              std          11.537029
                              min         -51.271695
                              25%          -1.000000
                              50%          -0.999322
                              75%          -0.951325
                              max          62.438258
```

How can I see the full output?

Comment: Maybe try outputting this object to a file and then open it with some text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're working with `pandas` so my first suggestion would be to change the number of rows displayed with

```
pandas.set_option('display.height', height)
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', rows)
```

Since the console also limits the output on its own you should also change the default buffer size (which is 500) of Ipython :

```
IPythonWidget.buffer_size : Integer
```

as described [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/options/qtconsole.html).